# Unique relations, how do I do this?

Tags: php, sql

I have an object named User, this object has a relation with the object Skill.
One User can have many skills and one Skill can belong to many Users.

But I want to do this and I don't know of what is the right approach:
One User can have many Skills but they must be unique, so e.g: Jason can't have the Skill "PHP" twice in his "skillset".

-----EDIT-----
I have a junction table between the two objects:
JTBL_User_Skill
for TBL_User and TBL_Skill

ID|User_ID|Skill_ID
1 |4|20
1 |4|20

The question:
I don't want any double entries in JTBL_User_Skill, how do I prevent this?

Comment: You need to add a many-to-many table between the two other tables, with the new table having one row for each unique pairing of user/skill.

Comment: Questions about "approach" generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help. If you're viewing this question, and have the tools, you should vote to close the question. #KeepStackOverflowClean

Comment: The last part "with the new table having one row for each unique pairing of user/skill", how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best thing to do is to have a table that bridges the two and contains a composite key of both user and skill (a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table))

For example, your user table might look like:

```
UserID (PK)
UserName
```

Your skills table:-

```
SkillID (PK)
SkillName
```

And therefore your junction table...

```
SkillID (PK)
UserID (PK)
```

...will link the two IDs together. This will allow your many-to-many relationship to exist, but you can only have one of the same skill per user and vice versa.

Comment: I have a junction table (JTBL_User_Skill), how do I make it so that there can't be any double entries in this table?

Comment: If the SkillID and UserID are a composite key there is no way you can have duplicate entries.

Comment: Awesome, that helped me alot. I searched for composite keys and I discovered that you need to set both the fields (User_ID and Skill_ID) as a primary key. Now they're unique, you have provided me an answer that was enough to research it myself so I can learn in the progress. Thank you for that.